# iOS Clipboard (Paste) Modification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to edit how users paste strings and pictures. My application would be simple: on or off. If it is on I want to be able to edit how the iphone pastes information into textboxes, programs, ect...

**My Goal**: The user can be on any application, but my application kicks in right when the user trys to paste something. When the user pastes something (on any application) I want a dialog box with a few options to come up. Is this possible, and if so are their any apple guides for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application SHOULD and WILL not be able to modify the behavior of other applications.  To have something just step in and modify a particular action so important as the pasteboard is IMHO really freaking scary and a serious security concern.  You are limited to your sandbox unless you jailbreak the phone.

Comment: That isn't to say that it's impossible.  I know there's probably somebody working on it.  But if you really want to disable/cripple/modify the access to the pasteboard, just do it in your own application.  The reference on UIMenuController shows how to remove buttons from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible, but it would have to be distributed on Cydia